# invalidate() inside of a thread android app

Tags: android, invalidation

I'm new to programming androids but I have quite a bit of experience programming blackberries.

I created an app that has an activity class (main.java) and a view class (game.java).

Inside the view class I have some bitmaps being drawn to the screen. I created a thread and I'm moving the images around in the thread. However when I call invalidate() inside the thread it never redraws the screen.

Are you not able to invalidate() the screen from a thread? I know the thread is running and the invalidate is being called, it just never makes the changes on the screen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to use [View.postInvalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29) if you call it from a non-UI thread.
According to docs:

> public void postInvalidate ()
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.

Comment: Wow that was too easy...I've been looking for the past 30 minutes on how to do it and I never once came across the postInvalidate().

Comment: Yeah, some functions have the bad habit of disapearing from docs when you search them ;)